# How to make the page be the width of iOS screen?

Tags: ios, css, html

Hello I'm having a problem whereas a page, where every element width is 100% looks like this in IOS / iPhone:

[image]

---

but it should look like this, as on the computer, where the width of all elements is adjusted to the width of the window:

[image]

Do you know how I fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with the viewport meta tag ? 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">`

Comment: Thank you! Your answer worked better than the one posted below because of some complications with my layout, so maybe you want to post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this within your `<head></head>` tags

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will tell the browser to use the full screen.

You can also set widths and other elements such as stopping zooming.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: It also helped me to add `height=device-height` to it

Comment: Ahh cool. Without knowing the HTML i guessed the problem would be the viewport as it normal is when working with mobile websites. Theres quite a few elements you can add to the viewport. The documentation and tutorials on them are usually very informative and really help on specific projects.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile devices you can use the viewport meta tag to adjust your interface. In your case you can use `width`and `initial-scale` to fit on the iPhone screen.

### Viewport width:

Specific width: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">`

Device width: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

### Zoom:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">`

### Others values:

- width: window width (`width="device-width"`)
- height: window height (`height="device-height"`)
- initial-scale: Initial Zoom (`initial-scale="1.0"`)
- minimum-scale: Minimum scale (`minimum-scale="0.5"`)
- maximum-scale: Maximum scale (`maximum-scale="3.0"`)
- user-scalable: If user can zoom on the page (`user-scalable="yes"`)